# MySQL Connection Checking From 'Form' using $_GET['']; and Array

Tags: php, html, mysql

Trying to connect to MySQL and Check Connection through a Form i have created. I'm using Array to store my variables and pass them to mysql_query(); , result i get is

> Failed to connect to Database.

by the way someone told me before to go with PDO, but have no clue on how to make PDO connection with array.

**I have tried:**

- echo `$_GET['hostname'];` - It Echo the form fields and other ones.
- Checking Syntax
- I have also put $_`GET['hostname'], $_GET['username'], $_GET['password'] $_GET['database'];` itself into mysql_query(); and no luck either

**Concern:**
By the way does anyone know if your phpmyadmin is located in /~username on mac will it still be useful by second or third directory? 
**example:**

> ~/username/app/index.php

**Index.php**

```
<form action="checkconnection.php" method="POST">
<label>Hostname:</label></span><br /><input autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="examples: (localhost etc)" name="hostname" id="hostname" type="text" /><br />
<label>Username:</label><br /><input name="username" id="username" type="text" /><br />
<label>Password:</label><br /><input name="password" id="password" type="text" /><br />
<label>Database:</label><br /><input placeholder="Your Database Name" name="database" id="database" type="text" /><br />
<button class="continue">Continue</button>
<button class="CheckConnection">Check Connection</button>
<button type="reset" class="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

**checkconnection.php**

```
<?php 

/*Database Checking and Result send back to Installation */
$dbLogin = array(
    'Hostname' => $_POST["hostname"],
    'Username' => $_POST["username"],
    'Password' => $_POST["password"],
    'Database' => $_POST["database"]
    );


$databaseConnection = mysql_query($dbLogin['Hostname'], $dbLogin['Username'], $dbLogin['Password'], $dbLogin['Database']);

if ($databaseConnection) {
    echo "Yes, your connection has been established.";
}else {

    echo "Failed to connect to Database.";
}

?>
```

Comment: replace `mysql_query($dbLogin ...` with `mysqli_connect`

Comment: Wow after all this connection i made before, look how small my problem was..Thanks man lol @FuzzyTree

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure to use MySQLi or PDO, as MySQL is outdated and has some security issues.

Then, replace

```
echo "Failed to connect to Database.";
```

with

```
echo $databaseConnection->connect_errno;
```

If it still doesn't work, then reply in a comment :)

Comment: I have tried echo $databaseConnection->connect_errno; and see what would i get if my stuff was wrong, it actually throw me blank page instead of some errors

Comment: If you are successfully connected, it won't give you an error :)

Comment: Yes i know, it would give me **Yes, your connection has been established.**, but what if i fail the connection? i try and it still give me no error

Comment: OK, try `echo $databaseConnection->error;`. I don't think that would do anything but it's worth a shot. The code I gave you before SHOULD work.

Answer (score 0):

You put this after your connection syntax. If you have any error related to database connection, then it will display the error.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: I have already fixed the issue (thanks to @FuzzyTree), by changing to mysqli_connect();, so i guess to cache error it should be `mysqli_connect_error();` but thank you for your extended help, cheer!:)

Answer (score 0):

check about

`mysql_connect()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

`mysql_select_db()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

`mysql_query()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php